# How to seed data in OnModelCreating with a Many-To-Many Relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

Im trying to seed data with a Many-To-Many Relationship. I have two classes, Actor and Movie.

```
public class Actor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; } = new List<Movie>();

public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; }
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; } = new List<Actor>();
    }
```

But i cant seem to figure out how to seed data in OnModelCreating

My initial thoughts were the method below.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
                .HasData(
                new Movie
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Title = "Terminator",
                    GenreId = 1,
                    Description = "...",
                    DirectorId = 1,
                    Actors = new List<Actor> { new Actor {  Id = 1, FirstName = "Arnold", LastName = "Schwarzenegger" },
                                               new Actor {  Id = 2, FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Biehn" },
                                               new Actor {  Id = 3, FirstName = "Linda", LastName = "Hamilton" }
                                              },
                    Price = 10.49,
                    ImageThumbnailUrl = "..",
                    IsInStock = true
                }
```

But i get the following error

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Movie' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Actors' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'ActorMovie (Dictionary<string, object>)' and specify the foreign key values {'MoviesId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.
```

Any suggestiongs to how to seed data with many-to-many relationship?